# Code coverage making mandatory

Tags: code-coverage

I would like to make code coverage mandatory during Sandbox to Sandbox deployment. How to achieve this?

We have created two Sandbox named dev and QA and would want to make code coverage mandatory while deploying from dev sandbox to QA sandbox so that while deploying to production we would not like to face hurdles. While through changeset its not possible, how about making mandatory through ANT migration tools like bit bucket, etc. How to make it mandatory through it?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to enforce code coverage on a Sandbox. If your deployment tools have "super admin" permissions, then you can set the test level to "RunLocalTests" or whatever on every deployment. Otherwise, developers can run whatever test they like, including none.

```
<deployOptions>
    <allowMissingFiles>false</allowMissingFiles>
    <autoUpdatePackage>false</autoUpdatePackage>
    <checkOnly>true</checkOnly>
    <performRetrieve>false</performRetrieve>
    <ignoreWarnings>true</ignoreWarnings>
    <rollbackOnError>true</rollbackOnError>
    <purgeOnDelete>false</purgeOnDelete>
    <singlePackage>false</singlePackage>
    <testLevel>RunLocalTests</testLevel>
</deployOptions>
```